# Algorithm for graph arboricity

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, matroids

I have a graph $G$ and I need to compute it's [arboricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arboricity). The arboricity is a minimal number of trees that cover all edges of the graph $G$.
By computing arboricity I mean not just getting the number (which is derived from the [Nash-Williams theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arboricity#Arboricity_as_a_measure_of_density)) but constructing this minimal number of trees.

Could anyone suggest an algorithm for this problem and explain how it works in general matroid case (as I've searched, arboricity is a matroid covering problem)?

Comment: Did you read the Gabow & Westermann paper linked to in the 'Algorithms' section of the wikipedia page for arboricity? It looks like Section 3 of that paper gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't think so, Section 3 is about matroid partitioning problem, what in a graph case will be dividing a graph into $k$ disjoint trees. But in my case, trees can intersect.

Comment: Such a minimal family of trees (forests, when there is more than one component) can intersect, but they needn't. This is the content of the word _partition_ in the first definition of arboricity on the wiki page: "The arboricity of an undirected graph is the minimum number of forests into which its edges can be partitioned." The issue is made even more transparent [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arboricity.html).

Comment: So if I need a minimal number of trees that cover the graph (and may intersect), I just find a minimal number of forests that partition the graph and then randomly add edges to forests so they become trees?

Comment: I haven't read the Gabow & Westermann paper closely enough to answer your question. But maybe it's time to do that. If you're interested in doing it together we can move this discussion into the graph theory chat (or some other appropriate forum) so we don't clutter this thread unnecessarily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65722/discussion-between-ivan-and-aaron-dall).